Question about window iridescence
Been reading about this and it seems like I may have a blown seal on a couple of my windows.

I am not sure if the whole window needs to be replaced or just a panel?
how much does something like this cost to replace if I can't do it myself
how can I figure out the manufacturer to see if there is a warranty? (house is 9 years old) They put stickers at the worst place and they all disintegrated.

Hard to capture but looks like this.




This is only symbol I could find


Are you sure that's not just some kind of oily subtance on the inside or outside of the IGU—have you tried washing?

If you are not seeing humidity between the panes, then this is something else.
The sealed units have multiple coatings on the glass to improve heat retention/ solar gain control and will explain some of this iridescence. Some sealed units are also filled with Argon gas to improve performance. If the gas escapes, there will be a small change in thermal performance.
You can replace them, however, the downside is that unless you know who manufactured the window and what glass supplier they used, chances are that the replacement units will have a different color of glass from the originals. Ten years is a long time in the glass business.
If the iridescence does not affect your view directly through the window (you can only see the effect at an angle) and you do not see humidity between the panes, I would leave the units alone for the sake of consistency with the other windows on the elevation.
